# Node.js, wait for all Redis queries to complete before continuing with execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I need to go through an array of values, look up date in Redis (to see if it exists), and then continue. For example:

```
var to_check = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
var found_elements = []

for (var i = 0; i < to_check.length; i++) {
  redis.EXISTS('namespace:' + to_check.length[i], function(err, value) {
    if (!err && value) {
      found_elements.push(to_check.length[i])
    }
  })
}

console.log(found_elements.join(', '))
```

I need to get the last line executed after all callbacks sent to Redis have been executed. What would be the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to handle complex async operations. Parallel execution is one of them.

```
var to_check = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
var found_elements = [];
Promise.all(to_check.map(function(item){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        redis.EXISTS('namespace:' + item, function(err, value) {
            if(err){
                return reject(err);
            }
            if (value) {
                found_elements.push(item);
            }
            resolve();
        })
    });
})).then(function(){
    console.log('All operations are done');
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: You can also directly use `Array.map` on `to_check` saving you a `forEach` + `push` : `var all = to_check.map(function(item) { return new Promise...});`

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there are other ways. But this should work(not tested):

```
var to_check = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
var found_elements = []

for (var i = 0; i < to_check.length; i++) {
(function(i){
      redis.EXISTS('namespace:' + to_check.length[i], function(err, value) {
              if (!err && value) {
                     found_elements.push(to_check.length[i])
              }
              if(i == (to_check.length-1)){
                   console.log(found_elements.join(', '))
              }
      })
 })(i);
}
```